# cleaning data - expanding one column to multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, stringr, tidy

The `textsample` below is in one column. Using R, I hope to separate it into 5 columns with the following headings: "Name" ,    "Location", "Date", "Time", "Warning" .  I have tried `separate()` and `strsplit()` and haven't succeeded yet. I hope someone here can help.

```
textsample <- "Name : York-APC-UPS\r\n
    Location : York SCATS Zigzag Road\r\n
    Contact  : Mechanical  services\r\n
    \r\n
    http://York-APC-UPS.domain25.minortracks.wa.gov.au\r\n
    http://192.168.70.56\r\n
    http://FE81::3C0:B8FF:FE6D:8065\r\n
    Serial Number : 5A1149T24253\r\n
    Device Serial Number : 5A1149T24253\r\n
    Date : 12/06/2018\r\n
    Time : 08:45:46\r\n
    Code : 0x0125\r\n
    \r\n
    Warning : A high humidity threshold violation exists for integrated Environmental Monitor TH Sensor 
   (Port 1 Temp 1 at Port 1) reporting over 50%CD.\r\n"
```

Comment: Is this a single record from which you have many, and you would like to extract only the columns you mentioned? If so could expand your text to include a few of those records (which would justify a table with columns)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that should at least get you started:

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` extract the text of interest with regular expressions.

Then we can use `mutate_all` to apply the same `str_replace` to get rid of the labels.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(extsample) %>% 
  extract(1, into=c("Name","Location","Date","Time","Warning"),
             regex = "(Name : .+)[^$]*(Location : .+)[^$]*(Date : .+)[^$]*(Time : .+)[^$]*(Warning : .+)[^$]*") %>%
  mutate_all(list(~str_replace(.,"^\\w+ : ","")))
#          Name               Location       Date     Time
#1 York-APC-UPS York SCATS Zigzag Road 12/06/2018 08:45:46
#                                                                                     Warning
#1 A high humidity threshold violation exists for integrated Environmental Monitor TH Sensor
```

This relies on capturing groups with `()`, see `help(tidyr::extract)` for details. We use `[^$]*` to match anything other than the end of the string 0 or more times between the groups.

Note the first argument to `extract` is `1`, which indicates the first (and only) column of the `data.frame` I made from your example data. Change this as necessary.